# Where does the phrase "meta means murder" come from?

Tags: discussion

When Meta is down, the now famous "Meta Means Murder" image is shown. Where does that phrase come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Meta is Murder](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html) by Jeff Atwood.

This is likely the original source of the phrase and of the image. As Shmork writes in a comment:

> I just spent 10 minutes looking for a "META IS MURDER" T-shirt before I realized that you had modified a "MEAT IS MURDER" one. D'oh.