# Make the MSE favicon grayscale (like all other meta icons are)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, meta, favicon

The new [favicon](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) for Meta Stack Exchange looks exactly the same as the one for the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/) site:

[image: Stack Exchange favicon]

This can get a bit confusing, especially if you happen to have many tabs open from both sites.  It also looks a bit silly in the site switcher menu:

[image: Screenshot of site switcher menu]

All the per-site metas (and MSO, even before the MSO/MSE split) have favicons that are grayscale versions of the main site icons.  Why not do the same for MSE?

Conveniently, michaelb958 already wrote a nice [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4639/greyscale-mse-favicon) to do just that (and I [extended](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/11071156) it to apply to the menu too), so you can easily see for yourself how it would look.  Or just see the screenshot below:

[image: MSE site switcher menu with grayscale icon]

So here's my proposal: **Let's make this gray icon the official MSE favicon.**

---

**Update:** The meta.SE favicon has recently been changed to a simplified outline version of the SE logo:

[image: Screenshot of new meta.SE logo]

I'm not sure how much I like the new logo (for one thing, it doesn't seem to match the dimensions of the main SE logo), but at least it's different, which was the main point of this request.

Comment: Ah, the question I forgot to write... Have my upvote, sir.

Comment: But it is *not* a regular meta site; it is *the* Meta meta site. It's the only one allowed to have colour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: We could always make it [rainbow-coloured](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227866/change-sites-background-to-rainbow-background), if you'd prefer. I'd be fine with that, as long as it was *somehow* distinct from the main stackexchange.com icon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In fact, I just mocked up [a rainbow SE favicon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wjOYB.png). Enjoy!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's the Meta site for Stack Exchange. Doesn't matter that Stack Exchange is not a Q&A.

Comment: Nice, missed this one! I consider closing my request as dupe of yours.

Comment: The new hollow better represents the "openness" of how Meta rules conformity

Comment: The hollow one is mostly fine by me, but [it looks terrible on dark browsers](https://i.3v.fi/1403822456.png) (mostly because of the white pixels) as I already mentioned in a duplicate post.

Comment: @3ventic: Those white pixels are definitely a bug. [Reported.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234684/new-meta-se-favicon-has-broken-transparency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I marked this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), even though it's partially completed. Like you said, the main goal was to differentiate the MSE favicon from the se.com favicon, and we've done that.

Since other people have asked for it to be grayscale, I'll just leave this here: we considered that, but decided against it because it doesn't make any sense to have a grayscale favicon for a page whose theme is blue and white, not grayscale.

Comment: meta theme should be [bloody red](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78577/where-does-the-phrase-meta-means-murder-come-from "'Meta Means Murder'") not blue :)

Comment: So just an empty square? Sorry but it's just a bad choice in my opinion.

Comment: it's a speech bubble...with nothing to say :(

Comment: The other answer contains [something much better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/96UIQ.png), it keeps the colors and not empty - is it being considered?

Answer (score 13):

I have a slightly different proposal. I kind of like the idea of a grayscale icon for Meta Stack Exchange, to be consistent with other child meta sites, but the problem with this:

[image: Grayscale icon]

is that it doesn't match the logo on Meta Stack Exchange

[image: Meta Stack Exchange logo]

which is unpleasantly inconsistent at best, and just downright a little confusing at worst. Granted, the old icon didn't match the Meta SE logo either, it was sort of the inverse.

### Alternative

I propose that the icon match the logo, i.e. a white balloon with horizontal blue stripes across:

[image: Match logo icon]

[image: Mockup with new icon]

This is with 2 horizontal bars instead of 3:

[image: Mockup with less bars]

So something like the above, except nicer looking (I'm not a designer with 1337 Photoshop skills).

Comment: I'm actually totally okay with the new fav icon now...so never mind.