# Please bring back the previous favicon (or change to grayscale)

Tags: feature-request, meta, favicon

Take a look at this:

> [image]

This is empty. Heartless. I won't say ugly, just bad. The worst favicon I've ever seen, and I saw my share in the last 20 years. It got no meaning, nothing.

Please change it back to the stacked, colorful, balloon. Please.

> [image]

If the purpose is having different icon than the main site, why not simple grayscale like all other meta sites in the network?

> [image]

Comment: Presumably it has been changed to differentiate it from the parent stackexchange.com favicon.

Comment: Not to mention it [looks terrible on dark browsers](https://i.3v.fi/1403822456.png)

Comment: @phenry might be, but there are other alternatives. Will think of something.

Comment: @3ventic yikes! wow, now that's ugly. :(

Comment: Please don't just revert; do something that's distinct from the standard SE favicon that's used for chat.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yep, fair point and I've added an alternative.

Comment: [rene brought up](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2145514#2145514) that [data.se] has the same logo, so it's confusing. Maybe give [data.se] a different logo?

Comment: @Cupcake yeah, better change SEDE favicon and possibly logo, if you got idea send it to Tim Stone who is kind of in charge over that site.

Comment: Well, you are always successful. I asked the same question and got -6.

Comment: @nicael where? Couldn't find it. I'm almost sure you used different words and/or way to display your idea.

Comment: [There](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234636/new-favicon-is-bad). Of course, I didn't add images, but I removed my question in a minute, because got 6 down votes (so I decided that everyone love new icon).

Comment: @nicael Jon Ericson summed it up nicely: you made it sound more like a rant than asking nicely to change. One thing I learned in Meta in all my years: what matters most is the attitude and the way you bring your argument forward, more than the argument itself sometimes.

Comment: By the way he posted his comment two minutes after I removed my post. How is it possible?

Comment: @nicael diamond mods (and of course SE employees who got a diamond) can post comments on deleted posts, plus many other cool powers.

Comment: @nicael as for my success rate, it's not great but it's measured by requests that get completed. For me it's currently [16](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A152859+%5Bfeature-request%5D+is%3Aquestion+%5Bstatus-completed%5D+closed%3Ano) out of [78](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A152859+%5Bfeature-request%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano) which appears to be indeed quite good, but it's not really measured by upvotes.

Comment: 2 of 6 for me :-) Yours is 20%, mine is 33% :-)

Comment: Good for you, @nic! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Well, aside from the jarring change, at least make the favicon match the site logo.  When I saw that icon in the reputation summary, I was at a loss as to which site it belonged to and why I'd be getting reputation there. I wondered if one of my meta questions had been migrated to a site I don't recall joining.

So, please, at least make it consistent across the site so I'm not left scratching my head.

Which logo refers to meta.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5):

Using a grayscale version of the (previous) icon would be consistent with other metas.  No it's not a per-site meta, but it *is* a meta for *all of Stack Exchange*, so users who see it on their profile, inbox, or achievements should not be confused.

Comment: Turns out it was [suggested long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/make-the-mse-favicon-grayscale-like-all-other-meta-icons-are), missed that.