# New meta.SE favicon has broken transparency

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, favicon

The new meta.SE favicon (the "hollow bubble") [looks awful on a dark background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/make-the-mse-favicon-grayscale-like-all-other-meta-icons-are#comment771683_230061):

[image: Screenshot by 3ventic]
[image: Zoomed in x4]

Note the stray light gray pixels in the corners, caused by broken transparency.

The issue appears to only affect the 16×16 pixel version of the favicon; the 32×32 pixel version embedded in the same file has correct transparency.  Also, even the transparency in the 16×16 pixel version is not *entirely* broken; some pixels in the lower right corner (visible as dark blue in the screenshot above) do have correct partial transparency.

Anyway, since this is a monochrome icon, reconstructing the correct transparency is pretty easy.  Here's a fixed version of the 16×16 px favicon (in PNG format, because imgur doesn't support ICO):

[image: Fixed 16×16 px favicon for meta.SE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for the fix. I totally forgot about dark themed desktops. I have updated our existing favicon with yours. The change will go out after the next production build.