# Meta icon is wrong on new mobile web

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web

First of all my compliments for the new look and feel of the mobile web. It looks very neat.

A small bug I found is regarding the icon of Meta in the nav bar list. It is showing an empty text balloon, not the Meta icon.

It could be by design, but it seems weird to me.

[image]

Comment: plug that phone in *now!* and [oblig xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1373/)

Comment: @mhlester: I waited an hour to get the battery at 1% for this screenshot. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon is correct. The icon for Meta.SE was changed to this new icon.

[image]

See [Make the MSE favicon grayscale (like all other meta icons are)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/make-the-mse-favicon-grayscale-like-all-other-meta-icons-are) — whilst it was declined, the icon was still changed; see the update section to the question.

Comment: That would explain it. Good catch on the feature request.