# How many meanings does the word "meta" have?

Tags: discussion, meta, wording

If there's any word that I have been so confused with, it's got to be **meta**. I have seen a few places where it's used in entirely different ways.

**Meta sites:** Here, meta means discussion about the site's working and policies.

**Meta tags:** Here, meta means unclassifiable, since meta tags can't be used to classify questions into specialized concepts.

**This post is way too meta IMO:** I've seen this being used a lot but I have no idea what it means.

Is this all, or are there other meanings to the word "meta"?

Comment: [Meta also means murder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78577/323179) :)

Comment: [What does 'meta' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/385192/185463)

Comment: I fail to see why was this post downvoted? Is this a stupid question?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48580/3946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: no other meanings, at least that I'm aware of.

---

The actual meaning depends on context. Few examples:

- "Please ask this on meta", when said in a main site, means of course the per-site meta. When saying this better link "meta" to the actual meta site, especially when telling this to new user.
- "This is too meta": this one is bit tricky. Usually it means whatever said is too "noisy", and went out of scope of the original post/discussion. Instead of talking about the post itself or original discussion, someone talk about something else.